# Using _.merge to update react state?

Tags: reactjs

```
 this.state = {
   children: {
     1: {
       id:1,
       name: 'hello',
     }
   }
 }
```

I'm trying to update one of children by the following code

```
 // given a child

 var state = _.merge({}, state, {
   children: {
     [child.id]: child
   }
 })
```

This looks simple, but most SO posts recommend `immutability helper` so I'm wondering if there's any flaw with the above approach?

Answer (score 0):

Note: This method mutates object.(Lodash documentation) i.e I think you shouldn't use it to return a new state.

Use `Object.assign` method or `{...object, newFieldValue}` ES6 spread operator

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
var state = Object.assign({}, state, { children: { [child.id]: child } })
```